# Having trouble with a SQL join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having a bit of a time trying to make this work...

I have one table that uses 1 or 2 digits for the week #. ( 1 to 52)

I have another table that uses 1 or 2 digits for the week# but also has the 2 digit year attached ( 117, 1017, 2217 etc.) ( 117 to 5217)

This is the only field that I can use to join these tables.

How can I join tableA with tableB on 1 = 117 or 12 = 1217...etc.?

The year portion can be omitted.

Comment: Is there any chance you can make all of the week numbers two characters (leading zero) to make this slightly more sane?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
SELECT a.Col1,b.Col1
FROM tablea a
JOIN tableb b ON (
        (LEN(b.Col1) = 3 AND a.Col1 = LEFT(b.Col1,1))
        OR
        (LEN(b.Col1) = 4 AND a.Col1 = LEFT(b.Col1,2))
)
```

This is assuming your datatypes are (n)varchar.  If they are INT or other numeric type you'll have to cast in the join clause.